Prove or disprove an identity involving a multidimensional integral
I'm reading a Physics article in which it is described the causality structure of the Coulomb Gauge ( the article is freely available here ) in a classical Electrodynamics setting:

The problem is that in order to prove that the Coulomb Gauge and the Lorentz Gauge give as it should be the same electric and magnetic field, one has to face this terrfying integral identity.
In order to prove the claim in the equation $\left(26\right)$ in the article, one has in fact to prove that:
\begin{align}
& \int d^3 \vec{r'} d^3 \vec{r''} \frac{(x_i-x_i^{'}) (x_j-x_j^{'})}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|^5|\vec{r'}-\vec{r''}|}\operatorname{J}_j(\vec{r'}-\vec{r''},t-|\vec{r'}-\vec{r''}|)
\\ = &
\\ & \
\int d^3 \vec{r'} d^3 \vec{r''} \frac{(x_i^{'}-x_i^{''}) (x_j^{'}-x_j^{''})}{|\vec{r'}-\vec{r''}|^5|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|}\operatorname{J}_j(\vec{r}-\vec{r'},t-|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|)
\end{align}

I don't understand why the two integral coincide,  supposing to exclude from the integration the region in which the denominators vanish and $i\neq j$ and using the Einstein Sum Convention.
Maybe the claim is false ?.



